# "This Class should provide a default constructor...." when building APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

My code compiles correctly throughout the whole app, and will emulate on an android phone. However when I begin to compile the APK to upload the app to Google Play, I come across this error. When I have looked up solutions and placed `public TouchImageView(){}`, I get another error that states:
   "Error:(44, 29) error: no suitable constructor found for ImageView(no arguments)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ImageView.ImageView(Context,AttributeSet,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)".

Does anyone have a solution to fix this so I can build my APK? My code is below (With the 'default constructor' included)

```
 package com.example.poweruser.fcemsandroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
    Matrix matrix;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    int viewWidth, viewHeight;

    static final int CLICK = 3;

    float saveScale = 1f;

    protected float origWidth, origHeight;

    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView() {}

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {

    super.setClickable(true);

    this.context = context;

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    matrix = new Matrix();

    m = new float[9];

    setImageMatrix(matrix);

    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    last.set(curr);

                    start.set(last);

                    mode = DRAG;

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (mode == DRAG) {

                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;

                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;

                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);

                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);

                        fixTrans();

                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);

                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    mode = NONE;

                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);

                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);

                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)

                        performClick();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                    mode = NONE;

                    break;

            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);

            invalidate();

            return true; // indicate event was handled

        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {

    maxScale = x;

}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        mode = ZOOM;

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

        float origScale = saveScale;

        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;

        if (saveScale > maxScale) {

            saveScale = maxScale;

            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;

        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {

            saveScale = minScale;

            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;

        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)

            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);

        else

            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();

        return true;

    }

}

void fixTrans() {

    matrix.getValues(m);

    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);

    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)

        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);

}



float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {

        minTrans = 0;

        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;

    } else {

        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;

        maxTrans = 0;

    }

    if (trans < minTrans)

        return -trans + minTrans;

    if (trans > maxTrans)

        return -trans + maxTrans;

    return 0;

}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {

        return 0;

    }

    return delta;

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight

            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)

        return;

    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;

    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {

        //Fit to screen.

        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)

            return;

        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;

        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;

        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image

        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);

        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);

        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;

        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;

        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;

        setImageMatrix(matrix);

    }

    fixTrans();

}
```

}

Comment: Get rid of the default constructor for `TouchImageView`. There should be no circumstance where you need it. If you're getting an error about needing a default constructor, you're doing something that shouldn't be done with `View`-based classes in Android.

Comment: Did you mistakenly add `TouchImageView` to your manifest?

Comment: your partial code listing doesn't include any constructors at all. Which means that a default no-args constructor is provided for you by the compiler, however your base-class (ImageView) doesn't  contain a no-args constructor. You must have at least one valid constructor. The simplest constructor for ImageView simply takes a Context. You may want to look at the docs for this -
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Comment: @TomDrake  Look again. `TouchImageView` currently has three constructors defined.

Comment: That's odd, that vertical scrollbar didn't show up earlier. Oh well, never mind.

Comment: @MikeM. *sigh* yes i did. I deleted it from my manifest and that fixed the problem. Thank you again for your help on my project!